# How not to show the default selected option in the drop down list

Tags: html, html-select

I have a select field like this

```
    <select name="user_code" >
        <option value="001">Code 1</option>
        <option value="002" selected>Code 2</option>
        <option value="003">Code 3</option>
     </select>
```

The default behaviour is, `code 2` is being shown as default selection, and `code 2`  appearing also on the drop down list after clicking the `select` field.
I don't want the default selected option to be displayed on the drop down list. Is it possible?

Comment: Why would you like to do this?

You can have a default value stored in a variable and only change it if the select is changed.

On this way you can have option -1 selected and only on change change the value of the variable...

Comment: Never mind i found the answer, all i need to do is to use inline css of display:none on the option with default selection

Answer (score 0):

Just to be complete, here another Version of achieving what you wanted with Javascript.

```js
document.getElementById("user_code").selectedIndex = -1;
var value = 002;
alert("Selected option: " + value);
function change(select){      
  for (var i = 0; i<select.options.length; i++){
    if (select.options[i].selected){
      value = select.options[i].value;
    }
  }  
  alert("Selected option: " + value);
}
```

```html
<select id = "user_code" name="user_code" onchange="change(this)">
        <option value="001">Code 1</option>
        <option value="002">Code 2</option>
        <option value="003">Code 3</option>
     </select>
```